# Yii routing - how to put that controller

Tags: php, yii, routes

I need to perform routing for the following url schemas:

```
website.com/some-category-name
website.com/some-category-name/entryName
```

some-category-name will be variable - some name of category

How to configure routing for this? I need to enter previous controllers, for example:

```
website.com/account
website.com/regiter
```

and want to everything that does not have controller name (so will be category name) going to controller Category.

I can't work it out.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
'urlManager' => array(
        'urlFormat' => 'path',
        'showScriptName' => false, 
        'rules' => array(
            'categoryName/<categoryName:\w+>' => array('site/category'),
            'register' => array('site/register'),
            'account' => array('site/account')
        ),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you must declare all rules for "non Category" actions, and after that dynamic rules (associated with category and antry):

```
'urlManager' => array(
    'urlFormat' => 'path',
    'showScriptName' => false, 
    'rules' => array(
        // for example if your account and register actions in user controller
        // ... you can write
        'account' => 'user/account',
        'register' => 'user/register',
        // or with one rule
        '<action(account|register)>' => 'user/<action>',
        // and for all other 'static actions', such as login, logout ...

        // after yhat you can declire dynamic rules
        '<categoryName:\w+>' => 'category/index',
        '<categoryName:\w+>/<entryName:\w+>' => 'category/entry'
    ),
),
```

So the code `Yii::app()->createUrl('user/register')` will generate url `website.com/register`, and accordingly the url `website.com/register` "goes to" *register* action of *user* controller (all other static rules like this way).

Now dynamic rules: code

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('category/index', array(
    'categoryName' => 'first-category-name'
))
```

will generate url *website.com/**first-category-name***, and vice versa: the url *website.com/**first-category-name*** "goes to" **category/index** action and in it will be available **$_GET['categoryName']** parameter, which will be equal to "**second-category-name**"․

Accordingly code

```
Yii::app()->createUrl('category/index', array(
    'categoryName' => 'some-category-name',
    'entryName' => 'some-entry-name'
))
```

will generate url website.com/**some-category-name/some-entry-name**, and in **category/entry** action you can get **$_GET['categoryName']** equal to "**some-category-name**" and **$_GET['entryName']** equal to **some-entry-name**.

I hope this help you to understand how works rules in Yii.

Thanks!